# Prevent StackView from animating

Tags: android, android-widget

I've an StackView android widget and I want it to don't animate automatically leaving always at the top the same item unless the user change it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about auto advance, this is specified in your widget xml file.

Do you have `android:autoAdvanceViewId="[your stack view]"` specified in the widget xml file? If so, that is the problem. Remove that line and it won't advance unless the user interacts with it.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I created the AppWidgetProvider from a sample and I didn't reviewed it for that. I checked the documentation but only for stackview, because I didn't remember neither expect to be in the provider.

Comment: How to do this at runtime? If you want to allow the user to choose between auto-advancing and not, it seems you have to have two providers: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=156273

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unfortunately. Please file a feature request at b.android.com.

Comment: Wow, I really doesn't expected that, in fact I found that a very common case. But thank your for replying :)

Comment: Opened feature request at  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21350

Comment: See reply from Adam Cohen below.